# Gradle sync failed in Android Studio for other than Google Services Dependencie

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed Android Studio on my MAC. I tried to add dependencies in gradle file. If I add Google dependencies, I am able to sync successfully. My problem is if I try to add any other dependencies apart from any Google services, Gradle sync failed every time I try to sync.

Below is my gradle file code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bhaskar.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48
<a href="openFile:/Users/bhaskar/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: Could you post the error message you got?

Comment: Could you include your build.gradle file from project root folder?

Comment: You should post your error gist and gradle file code, to figure out the issue.....

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu thank you for your response. I have updated my question. Please check once.

Comment: @Rakesh add text of error

Comment: @Divers i have updated question. Please check.

Comment: @Rakesh probably your gradle in offline mode? Preference -> build, execute -> gradle